# What is the humor in "water's warm and deep" while relieving oneself?

Tags: humor, books, jokes

> The two men halted at the edge of the canal, hiked their tunics, then
> fumbled with their loincloths. Soon two arcs were gurgling across the
> filmy surface. “Hmm,” Xinemus said. “**The water’s warm**.” Even
> terrified, Esmenet rolled her eyes, smiled. “**And deep**,” the Prince
> replied. Xinemus cackled in a manner at once wicked and endearing.
> After securing himself, he slapped the other man on the back. “I’m
> going to use that,” he said merrily, “the next time I piss back here
> with Akka. If I know him, he’ll damn near fall in.” “You’ll have a
> rope to throw him at least,” the taller man replied. More laughter, at
> once hale and warm.
>
> --- The Darkness That Comes Before by R. Scott Bakker

*The water's warm* is probably referring to the warm sensation of pee but how does it relate to *And deep*?

Comment: The men are joking about their penises. Xinemus pretends that he can feel the temperature of the water in the canal with his penis (i.e. that it it is long enough to reach at least the surface of the water). The Prince extends the joke by pretending that his own penis is even longer, enough to reach the bottom of the canal (and thus measure its depth). Finally the 'taller man' (the Prince) compares Xinemus' penis to a rope.

Comment: There ought not to be a comma after 'terrified'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks. I missed probably the funniest moment of the otherwise dark novel ;)

Comment: It's not all that funny.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Which speaks more about the gravity throughout the book than the joke :D

Comment: It sounds like swords-and-sorcery or some allied fantasy genre. Often heavily male orientated and US in flavour. Do not expect great literature (or even good writing) in this category of fiction. This is just my personal opinion; fee free to ignore it if you wish.